# Let $c_i$ be eigenvalues of $C$ what is $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{c_i})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $c_i$ be eigenvalues of the matrix $C$.

What would  $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{c_i})$ corespond to?

I don't think it's $\det(1+ C^{-1})$, right?

Comment: Well, what is $\det(C)$ in terms of its eigenvalues? And what is $\det(C^{-1})$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $C$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, then $c_i+1$ will be the eigen value for the matrix $C+I$. Since the product of the eigen values is the determinant of the matrix, therefore the given product is 
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{c_i+1}{c_i}\right)=\frac{\text{det}(C+I)}{\text{det} C}=\text{det}(C^{-1})\text{det}(C+I)=\text{det}(C^{-1}+I)$$

Comment: ... and thus it is indeed $\det(I+C^{-1})$.